# Terraform conditional creation of Service endpoint for a subnet

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-virtual-network, terraform-provider-azure

I have a terraform script for creating a virtual network and subnets in azure. The code inherits a module which has the  both creation of vnet and subnet. I am trying to create a VNET and two subnet, but want to enable service end point for a specific subnet only. **Need help on how to do it**

```
module "vnet" { 
        source                          = "./modules/VirtualNetwork"
        VirtualNetwork_Name             = "${var.prefix}-${var.resource_group_name}-VNET1"
        Resource_Group_Name             = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
        Location                        = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.location
        VirtualNetwork_AddressSpace     = ["10.4.0.0/23"]
        Subnet_Name                     = ["snet-1","snet-2"]
        Subnet_Addresses                = ["10.4.0.0/24","10.4.1.0/24"]
       
        Service_Endpoints               = vnet.Subnet_Name == "snet-1" ? ["Microsoft.AzureCosmosDB"] : [""]
   
if subnet=="snet-1" then ["Microsoft.AzureCosmosDB"] else ["nothing"]

        Tags                            = {
                                                environment     = "prod"
                                                resource        = "VNET"
                                                cost_center     = "Test Cost Ceneter"
                                            }                       

}
```

The below code is for network module

```
# Creates the virtual network for the resources
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {

  name                = var.VirtualNetwork_Name
  location            = var.Location
  resource_group_name = var.Resource_Group_Name
  address_space       = var.VirtualNetwork_AddressSpace
  tags                = var.Tags
}



# Create two subnet for the vnet
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {

  name                    = var.Subnet_Name[count.index]
  address_prefix          = var.Subnet_Addresses[count.index]
  resource_group_name     = var.Resource_Group_Name
  virtual_network_name    = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  count                   = length(var.Subnet_Name)
  # service_endpoints       = ["Microsoft.AzureCosmosDB"]
  service_endpoints       = var.Service_Endpoints
}
```

Comment: What is your issue exactly? you can't find documentation around that? You deployment throws errors ?

Comment: @thomas , if you read the question, u will understand what i am asking  I am trying to create a VNET and two subnet, but want to enable service end point for a specific subnet only. Need help on how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**./modules/VirtualNetwork only the subnet creation part**

```
# Create two subnet for the vnet
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {

  name                    = var.Subnet_Name[count.index]
  address_prefix          = var.Subnet_Addresses[count.index]
  resource_group_name     = var.Resource_Group_Name
  virtual_network_name    = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  count                   = length(var.Subnet_Name)
 
  service_endpoints       =  element(var.Service_Endpoints,count.index) 
}
```

**main.tf**

```
module "vnet" { 
        source                          = "./modules/VirtualNetwork"
        VirtualNetwork_Name             = "${var.prefix}-${var.resource_group_name}-VNET1"
        Resource_Group_Name             = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
        Location                        = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.location
        VirtualNetwork_AddressSpace     = ["10.4.0.0/23"]
        Subnet_Name                     = ["snet-1","snet-2"]
        Subnet_Addresses                = ["10.4.0.0/24","10.4.1.0/24"]
       
        Service_Endpoints               = [["Microsoft.AzureCosmosDB",""], [""]] 
}
```

The key is to pass the service end point as a list Service_Endpoints               = [["Microsoft.AzureCosmosDB",""], [""]]. Based on the index of the subnet it will assign the service end point

Answer (score 3):

According to your requirement, you just want to enable a service endpoint for a specific subnet only. You can set the [conditional-expressions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) in the `azurerm_subnet` block.

You could change the code like this and I have validated it on my side.

**main.if** in the root directory.

```
variable "subnet_name" {
    default = ["subnet1","subnet2"]
}
# retrieve a specific subnet via the index of subnet list.
locals {
    subnet_name_enable_service_endpoint = element(var.subnet_name,0)
}

...

module "vnet" { 
       
        source                          = "./modules/VirtualNetwork"
        VirtualNetwork_Name             = "${var.prefix}-${var.resource_group_name}-VNET1"
        Resource_Group_Name             = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
        Location                        = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
        VirtualNetwork_AddressSpace     = ["10.4.0.0/23"]
        Subnet_Addresses                = ["10.4.0.0/24","10.4.1.0/24"]
        Subnet_Name                     = var.subnet_name
        specfic_subnet_name             = local.subnet_name_enable_service_endpoint
        Service_Endpoints               = ["Microsoft.AzureCosmosDB"]

        Tags                            = {
                                                environment     = "prod"
                                                resource        = "VNET"
                                                cost_center     = "Test Cost Ceneter"
                                            }                       

}
```

Network module configuration is in the path `./modules/VirtualNetwork`.

```
# declare a variable for accepting the specific subnet.
variable "specfic_subnet_name" {
    
}
...
#Create Virtual Network in Primary Resource Group
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "primary" {
  name                = var.VirtualNetwork_Name
  resource_group_name = var.Resource_Group_Name
  address_space       = var.VirtualNetwork_AddressSpace
  location            = var.Location

  tags = var.Tags

}


#Create Subnet in Virtual Network
resource "azurerm_subnet" "primary" {
  count = length(var.Subnet_Name)
  name                 = var.Subnet_Name[count.index]
  resource_group_name  = var.Resource_Group_Name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.primary.name
  address_prefixes     = [element(var.Subnet_Addresses,count.index)]
  service_endpoints    = element(var.Subnet_Name,count.index) == var.specfic_subnet_name ? var.Service_Endpoints : [""]
  
}
```

Comment: If you see the above code will create 2 subnets and enable service endpoints for both the subnets. I need to do it for only one of the subnets

Comment: Yes, do you try my configuration files? It just enable services endpoints for one specific subnet snet-1 in my example. I use `service_endpoints   = element(var.Subnet_Name,count.index) == "snet-1" ? var.Service_Endpoints : [""]` in the `azurerm_subnet` block.

Comment: I am using a module and seems like you are asking me to write the condition in the module which is not desirable. If i put the same code in the place i consume the mode i.e module "vnet" { , i get the following error. Error: Reference to "count" in non-counted context

  on 02_VirtualNetworks.tf line 11, in module "vnet":
  11:         Service_Endpoints              = element(var.Subnet_Name,count.index) == "snet-1" ? ["Microsoft.AzureCosmosDB"] : [""]

The "count" object can be used only in "resource" and "data" blocks, and only
when the "count" argument is set.

Comment: I mean to write the condition in the azurerm_subnet block in the configuration files. You may copy all my configuration file, I edit some places according to your configuration files. This works on my side.  The main configuration is under the root directory, the Network module configuration files are under `/modules/VirtualNetwork`.

Comment: unfortunately didnt work, but i took a cue out of your approach and solved it in a different way. see the response below

Comment: I suggest trying my solution again and if my solution is helpful and also it could help other people in the same scenario. Please accept it as an answer,

Comment: unfortunately, the solution didn't work for me. You cant hardcode values inside a module when u are trying to define it as reusable component.

Comment: I dont understand you mean that hardcode inside a module？I seems that both solution looks the same but my solution include dynamic conditional expression.

Comment: If I need to create a new VNET/Subnet, I can inherit my module and assign values for VNET name/address same for Subnet name/address. With your option i need to make sure the subnet name always snet-1. I am creating modules to reusability purpose

Comment: I see. at the original, I just follow your question`if subnet=="snet-1" then ["Microsoft.AzureCosmosDB"] else ["nothing"]`. In this case, you just need to provide a variable for that dynamic specific subnet. Please check my edit. The logic is the same.